# SAS enterprise guide summing by personal ID

Tags: sas, enterprise

I have a dataset which has multiple obs per person. I want to have each single record showing the sum of a variable per person ID. However I do not want to group the data into single personal IDs. I hope the example below explains my question

I want to create the column in bold. How to do this? In SAS EG (or SAS if necessary)?

ID...Var1...**SUM**
X.....10.......30
X.....20.......30
Y.....20.......80
Y.....20.......80
Y.....40.......80
Z.....30.......30

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide an example of the *starting* dataset, and then an example of the *result* dataset.

Comment: Are you asking for how to do it with the point and click interface, or with programmatic statements?

Comment: JDB, I agree it could be more clear. Basically the starting dataset is the data in the first two columns, the resulting dataset is the three columns combined. And i prefer to have it solved in the point and click way, but a program can be written as well in SAS EG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using either `proc sql` or `proc means`
more info:[proc means](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146734.htm)

[proc sql](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/268-29.pdf)

proc sql:

```
proc sql noprint;

    create table new_table as
    select distinct id, var1, sum(var_to_sum) as summed_var_name
    from old_table
    group by id
    ;
quit;
```

after rereading your question, using proc means you will need to merge var1 back in, better off using proc sql above.

proc means:

```
proc means data = old_table sum;
    by id var1;
    var var_to_sum;
    output out = new_table sum;
run;
```

Comment: I realise it is a bit late. But this answer works fine! Thanks a lot Scott ;)